# Using Open= in an autorun file does not open anything

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, autorun, inf

Note: This is in a registered copy of Windows 10 running 21H2 (Build 19044.1645)

I made sure that everything else is fine by using `icon=icon.ico` and that runs fine, same with `label=` but for whatever reason `open=` does not seem to work.

my autorun.inf looks like the:

```
[autorun]
Open=test.exe
Label=This is a USB
Icon=test.exe
```

and `test.exe` is compiled from a python script using [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/) and looks like this:

```py
import turtle as tl

for n in range(360):
  fd(2)
  rt(2)

input()
```

with the `input()` call meant to make the turtle window not close immediately

What have I done wrong, and how do I fix it?

**Clarification**
I have a USB drive that I want to run an `exe` file as soon as it is plugged in. This exe file is currently just a simple debugging program, but will later be used to organize drives. I read that an `autorun.inf` file would be the best way to do this, and so I tried what the article said. But to no avail. What do I need to do to the code or drive to make it run?

Comment: Does it work in the context menu of the drive?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Anders I assume you are wonderiung if the cotext menu of the drive has a `Run autoplay` entry. It does. That opens a menu with "Configure storage" and "View files"